# how can I delete the last element in the array?

Tags: c

In the given code, there is a method that

```
for(i = pos - 1 ; i < size -1 ; i++)
{
a[i] = a[i+1] ;
}
```

but suppose the size is 4 and I want to delete the 4th position value of the array. 
In this scenerio I am not able to understand how this code will work.

Comment: You can’t resize an array. How is `a` declared?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The code you post it is not for deleting purposes so... which one is your real question?

Comment: After delete you just pretend it has one less element.

Comment: What Antti is proposing would be to just decrement `size` for the rest of the program. But don't try to ever increase it beyond the actual `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you do not quite understand how arrays are in C.

In C, an array is a continuous sequence of items of the same type and therefore same size.

The system will allocate space for the array initially.

For example when you say `int a[4]` and run your function, `a` is of type "array of `int`", each entry is type of 'int'.
Mostly, an int value needs 4 bytes of space. And the `[4]` means space for four ints will be allocated. That is, it will allocate 4*4=16 bytes in your memory.

For example, down here is the spaces allocated by `a`:

`01010101        first byte (start of a[0])
01111110        second byte
00101001        third byte
00000111        fourth byte
01100000        fifth byte (start of a[1])
.....
.....
.....
01010101        16th  byte`

While it is just allocated, the bytes value is unknown. You can initialize or assign value to it.

Okay, then when you use `a` to do something, you can say `a[1]` to access the int represented by the 4 bytes ranging from the 5th byte to the 8th byte.

What will happen if you say `a[10]`?
The space is not allocated by your program! Accessing it is an error. But only if you are lucky maybe an error tip window showing "Access Violation at memory 0x6463a80 (the number is just example)" or you get a value unknown without a noticeable warning and that would be worse!

From your question, I know that you want to say,
"Oh gosh, I originally have `int a[4]`, but later in the code, I want to shrink it to something like `int a[3]`!"

The solution is: just ignore `a[3]`, view it as it does not exist! Never use `a[3]` then that's okay!

If you want to have a full access of operations like "Add" "insert" "Remove" etc. Array is not suitable. Consider C++. It has std library, and there is Vector type. It's not array, it works different from this. Search Google or chat me if u want to know.

You may be not completely understand what I am saying here but please feel free to ask. I'm almost on the same boat with you and I am willing to teach & help you.

Comment: Good edit. I like the answer. I took some liberty in brushing it up, maybe slightly beyond the usual limits of editing. Feel free to undo anything you do not like and please accept my apology in that case. I left in the use of the term `allocate` which is not strictly correct for statically mapped/linked arrays. Consider doing a larger edit to make that perfect.